# How can I determine if any cell within a range is used/referenced anywhere else in WorkBook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have just inherited a Workbook and I am trying to audit and document all the functions used.

The workbook has a good number of worksheets (+20) some of which are imported from CSV files while others are computed and re-used elsewhere in the workbook. In particular I have multiple ranges of data that have hundreds of values. I want to determine if any of these values are referenced/used elsewhere in a Excel workbook since we know that there is a huge amount of redundant data in the workbook.

Is there standard Excel functionality that I can use to achieve this? Or would I need to write a macro?

I could possibly, do a cell-by-cell analysis - but that could takes me days if not weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.brighthub.com/office/home/articles/2020.aspx for single field dependency search and you can refer to http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=410195 for a macro approach.

It looks like it is not possible to use the excel provided functionality of finding dependent cells for multiple cells at once. So macro will be the feasible option for you.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do this, I use [Ozgrid's Formula Manager](http://www.ozgrid.com/Services/Excel_Formula_Add-in.htm) then just use Ctrl-F on the report page to search for the item.